# Add a link with the list of moderators?

Tags: feature-request, moderators

To be consistent with the badge & tags system, it would be nice to add a link on the ♦ character to the list of moderators

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full list of Moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/full-list-of-moderators)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd This is certainly *not* a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @N.N. sorry, thought he meant just a plain list didn't notice he wanted the diamond to become clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about

Scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Yup. Would a link to this FAQ entry be possible on the ♦ character ?

Answer (score 5):

I disagree. If the diamond were a link, I would expect it to be part of the same link as the username. This behavior would (very slightly) confuse and irritate me.

Comment: When you hovered over it the underline would indicate that it was a distinct link. It's not initially obvious (nor are the many tooltips), but it's not terribly confusing once discovered.