# Full list of Moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators, stackexchange.com, moderator-faq

While having a [little chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2220736#2220736) tonight with [studiohack](https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack) over at [Super User](https://superuser.com/), he made a comment about how we have around 150-200 moderators on SE total. I thought about this for a moment, and realized that seeing ALL the moderators we have could be tricky. Going to 60+ sites and looking at their `about` pages is time consuming.

My idea is that we could have a **full list of moderators**, perhaps on [StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), where we can see **every single moderator** on all of the 60+ sites out there. I think it would be neat to see who is running everything around here.

Comment: Maybe another tab in http://s.tk/team to list all the sites and their moderator's gravatars?

Comment: @JeffMercado interesting idea!

Comment: @JeffMercado or user flairs, instead of gravatars, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not opposed, but if you're e.g. a Stack Overflow user, why would you care who the Cooking mods are?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek A lot of people use MANY of the sites, and look to participate on more of them

Comment: @SimonSheehan Well, if you're on a bunch of sites you probably know the mods on those sites. Why would you want a list of all mods, including sites you don't care about?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I'm thinking more along the lines of common knowledge for everyone to access. It could even help users to visit new sites - perhaps they see a moderator they know and like. It could attract them to look at the site. It could also be a nice appreciation thing for our moderators.

Comment: @JeffMercado the moderators are already list on the sites `/about` page

Comment: @ChrisF: But we're talking about a listing of all moderators from all sites all listed in one place, not just the mods per site.

Comment: @JeffMercado - I realise that it's not a central location, but just pointing out the information does exist. The other drawback with the `/about` page is that for higher rep users the link isn't immediately available.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I just dont understand half of these comments...  Why would anyone prefer **not** to know something? Its like open source, if you dont like it, dont use it, but why try to prevent others from using it?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We finally added an *all network moderators* page to stackexchange.com:

https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators

You can categorize by and search for sites or users, and expand each section to see profile details. (Right now, information on the page is cached and updated daily.)

Let us know if there's anything else we can add to the page to make it more useful.

Comment: in the details you could add when a mod was appointed/elected, like the about pages

Comment: @Emmet. can we make it so that when you open a dropdown of a site, then click on a mods name, when you go back it should still have the dropdown open (it does **not** do that currently)

Comment: @DForck42 AFAIK we show that data wherever we have it (i.e. wherever it's shown on the site's about page, it's also shown on this page). We do need to backfill some missing data though.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA yeah i see that now.

Comment: well i know me, ladenedge, and tml were appointed to lit in 2011.  is there a good place/person to tell that to?

Comment: @Emmett It's missing the "fun" stats from Mark Trapp's answer. :)

Comment: Fun stats would be really cool to see! Also, this is great, thanks for the hard work!

Comment: Aww, you used `<div class="mods-item mods-item-UniqueNumber">` instead of `<div class="mods-item" id="mods-item-UniqueNumber">`, so we can't link directly to a row in the table.  Classes aren't supposed to be unique, use IDs for this purpose!

Comment: It shows elected dates but I'm not seeing appointed dates for pro-tems, even when they're on the sites.  (For example, Writers shows appointment dates but my entry on the all-mods page doesn't.)  Thanks!  Very useful page BTW.

Answer (score 15):

This felt interesting to tinker with so I coded my take (with much help and many corrections in moderator chat):

<del>www.rarst.net/experiments/se-mods.php</del> (no longer live, since now there is official implementation)

Unfortunately flair blocks you out for that many requests, so had to use gravatars.

Comment: Very cool, although it took me a very long time to load it.

Comment: @Simon Sheehan long time on every load or first load? Data is pulled from API (not hardcoded), so when cache expires it takes quite a bit of time for code to query each site for moderators.

Comment: Seems to be fast now, its good!

Comment: @Rarst - It's now [status-planned], and I don't think they'll be using PHP, but I get a great big "Error establishing a database connection" when I visit your site.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer my server had melted or something. Support politely put it as "emergency hardware maintenance". Should be back up as of now.

Comment: @Rarst - Yes, it seems back up.  Pretty nice work! Personally, I'd sacrifice some of the big eye-candy icons to get some information like names, though.

Comment: @Rarst I noticed Anna Lear is not on the list. Are you excluding folks with more than 3 diamonds?

Comment: @wax eagle yep, that was criteria used to get most of SE employees filtered out. There is no way to distinguish them from just mods.

Comment: @Rarst SE employees are mods on *all* sites. If someone is not a mod in any site they are registered, they can be excluded as a SE employee.

Comment: @NullUserException from what I understood when I was creating and cleaning this up in mod room (1) they are not necessarily mods on ALL sites (I may be mistaken on this), (2) they are not necessarily have same names on all sites. So check "if name present in all sites" would not be reliable.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right.