# Community moderators should have an access to private betas without commitment

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Why? It is often quite handy to sneak in and see if the newborn site is not going into conflict with the one you moderate or to give external voice in certain meta threads.
Now it requires either fake commitment (which leads to stuck/unfilled commitments and thus slowing down new proposals) or using API and/or private beta users to bypass the system (so the current policy filters out almost *exclusively* harmless sneaks).

Why not not? It is not harmful since there is not too many of us and we are an aware users -- thus this won't alter the privateness of private beta.

Comment: There are [200+ community moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/full-list-of-moderators/109889#109889) right now.

Comment: @AnnaLear Precisely.

Comment: Sorry, let me elaborate. I wouldn't call that "not too many of us". For a brand new private beta site, that's potentially overwhelming.

Comment: Well, this is why it is "not too many" not "few" -- it is nothing in comparison to whole SE audience, thus it does not change the general idea that beta is private. And I don't get how this may be overwhelming -- if some would plan to cause non-negligible impact, he would have no reason no to go in through commitment.

Comment: Are you saying that random mods dropping in on a private beta to offer advice would result in negligible impact? If so, why do it? I don't think a comparison to the entire SE audience is relevant. We should be considering the population of the new site instead. The community team exists to guide new SE sites at the beginning. There's no need for random people with marginal interest in the subject to come in. And if your interest is not marginal... yoda covered that in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why other site moderators should be allowed to circumvent the commitment process and be allowed access to the site. If you feel that there is a site coming up that might encroach upon your site's territory, you should've brought that up *before* the site went into private beta, during the Area51 phase!

If that wasn't possible then or if you were unaware of the proposal prior to its launch, then you should, in your site's interests, jump in and participate to steer the ship away from your site.

What you're trying to do is be a goat herder without any concern for the goats. We don't like that.

Comment: Ok, I can take your point; though I'm convinced this will become less exceptional problem over time.

Answer (score 6):

[We already do have public read-only access to private betas through the API.](http://sa.column80.com/?api=143) If the newborn site has a chatroom (*which it totally should*), we can chime in there as well.

I don't think, however, that "sneaking people in" will leave a good taste in the mouth of people that did work hard to secure a spot and launch the site. SE employees are already *barely tolerated* on some sites, let alone random strangers that happen to have been chosen by other people in other sites...

Comment: Because its such a good idea to throw away other users experience that they painstakenly gained from trying to solve similar problems. Just because some users are idiots for not tolerating SE employees, doesn't mean we should all copy that behavior

Comment: Curious those people want to reach public beta...

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget that you can get an invite to a private beta from an existing member. So as long as you can find someone prepared to send you one (another moderator who committed perhaps?) then you can gain access that way.

Comment: tc;df (more characters)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this one.