# What does the number on the favorites tab mean?

Tags: support, profile-page, notifications, bookmarks

I went to my user page this weekend and was surpised to see this:

[image: 34 fAvOrItZ!]

I only have 11 questions favorited, so I thought that 34 seemed a bit high.  Then I realized that I actually have no idea what that number means.  I found an awesome answer by [yoda](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160166/yoda) to this question:

[What does highlighting mean on the profile's "Favorites" tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/what-does-highlighting-mean-on-the-profiles-favorites-tab/114277#114277)

But, his observations ("The number next to the tab indicates how many posts have new answers since you last visited the tab") do not match up with what I'm seeing:

- I don't have 34 questions favorited, so I don't think it's a count of questions with new answers
- It doesn't seem to be a tally of all the new answers on my favorited questions either (because there are only 32 answers total to those 11 questions).

**Could we get a clear definition of what this number means?**  This is obviously not a high-priority request, I'm just curious =)

<sub>I have left [my favorites page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/168428/jadarnel27?tab=favorites) the same for now, in case that is helpful to anyone doing detective work on this feature =)</sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the sum of new answers, edits to the question, and comments on the question, but I'm not sure how best to test that.

Comment: Commenting, for science!

Comment: Also a second comment, for no good reason. Also, unicorns rule.

Comment: I was just gonna ask this same question! What's funny is that my tab said 34 also!

Comment: @Cole 34 must be the threshold for interest in that number =)

Comment: Wow!  I just assumed that this was a bug that went unfixed for years :-)  Not very good UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is still valid (hence posting as an answer rather than voting to close), but [Jeff once wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3155/show-updates-to-favorite-questions-in-recent-activity/3808#3808):

> if you favorite a question, you opt in to updates on that question [...] **just as if you own the question**.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Based on my observations so far, this looks like it pretty much answers the question.  Thanks Arjan =)

Comment: They [are highlighted](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jvbVQ.png), @Phillip, but [only once](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qPvl2.png).