# What does the blue number on the Bookmarks tab show?

Tags: support, meta, bookmarks

Here is a screenshot on **Meta StackOverflow** showing 46 new bookmarks although I have only 2 bookmarks:

[image: Screenshot of 46 bookmarks]

Not sure what this number is. Perhaps the total number of "new bookmarks" across all the StackExchange network?

Here is a screenshot of my **StackOverflow** profile showing 41 new bookmarks, which is probably the correct number, which is probably included in the number on **Meta StackOverflow** (and the 5 others from other StackExchange sites?):

[image: Screenshot of 41 bookmarks]

Same issue on **Meta StackExchange**, but with a different number and I don't have an explanation for this one (shows 9 new bookmarks although I have only 5 bookmarks):

[image: Screenshot of 9 bookmarks]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the number on the favorites tab mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119236/what-does-the-number-on-the-favorites-tab-mean)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The blue number isn't the number of newly-created bookmarks. It's the number of times the items in your bookmarks have been active since the last time you opened that tab. It's how you know that there has been activity on one or more of those bookmarks.

When the number of active bookmarks is higher, that should mean that one or more of the bookmarks has been active multiple times.

So, I haven't added any new bookmarks here on MSE in months, but my bookmarks tab indicates 13 events.

When I open my bookmarks and sort by activity I see this:

[image: Screenshot of bookmarks, active tab. There's a blue "13" next to the tab name, "Bookmarks". Below, there are 21 bookmarks listed, of which the top eight are highlighted in yellow, indicating they were recently active. The ninth is visible at the bottom, but is not highlighted.]

These eight yellow bookmarks were active since the last time I visited this tab - this tells me, if I want to check to see if anything has changed, these are the ones I might be interested in reviewing. Since 8 is less than 13, I also know that some of these were active more than once. These changes are generally either new answers or edits to the question.

Once I've clicked on the tab, the next time I visit my profile, the blue number is gone along with the yellow highlighting:

[image: A similar screenshot to the previous but the blue 13 is gone and only the top three questions are visible, but they're no longer yellow.]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't the blue number on every other tabs the number of new things (new answers, new questions, new badges, new reputations, new responses, etc)? It's confusing that the blue number on the Bookmarks tab represent something else. Also, the number of newly-created bookmarks would be an interesting metric.

Comment: It's the number of events - new activity - on each tab. So, in that sense, the activity on a bookmarked question *is* new activity. :) We assume that people know when they add bookmarks but they may not know when those bookmarks are active. By drawing attention to the recently-active ones like this, it helps users keep track of the posts they asked us to help them keep track of.