# Where can I find a list of site moderators?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Full list of Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/full-list-of-moderators)

As I recall, all of the site's community moderators used to be listed on the bottom of the `/about` page.  With the new revision, this seems to have been lost.

Where should one go to easily find this information now?  If there is no longer a dedicated location that lists the moderators?  If so, could we have it added back to a logical place like the FAQ or `/about`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [full listing of all moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) on the main Stack Exchange site, as well as a ["moderators" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) on the Users page of each individual site.

Comment: As Yannis said in his now-deleted answer, the user tab appeared together with the new about page *because* the section was removed from about.

Comment: How often is that list updated? [Oded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) earned his diamond, but isn't on that list.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Oded is an employee, not a moderator (for the distinction used for these lists).

Comment: So ♦ != "diamond mod"? My world is crumbling. What's the distinction between the two states? I always assumed

Comment: @mikeTheLiar If they're a diamond on all sites, they're an employee.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar He has moderator privileges, but he has them because he is employed by Stack Exchange as opposed to having been elected by the community for the purposes of moderating the site.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the mod page strictly lists elected mods?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar That's essentially correct, yes.