# How many moderators are there on SE?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I'm looking for a simple count of all moderators.  It can be as of now or as of a week ago.  It should be reasonably accurate and up-to-date but it doesn't have to be exact.

I would like:

1. The total number of moderator positions.
2. The total number of SE users who are moderators for at least one stack.

In 2011, the post [Full list of Moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109875/full-list-of-moderators) led to the creation of the very useful [Moderators](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators) page.  It doesn't tell me the total though; I'd have to count (and cutting out duplicate names would be hard). Is there a resource to make this task easier?

I've done an extensive search with no luck, but I did find that [there are 173 stacks](https://stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: A [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906090/all-moderators-with-site-and-database-name) that could be slightly modified by one of our resident experts is a good starting point.

Comment: @Rob Okay, 663 total moderator positions as of Oct 2018.  That is helpful, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but there are a few Mods called "Rob", etc. - so the person modifying the query would want to match to the main ID and use that to eliminate duplicates. Also some of those people have quit, the list is updated each Sunday.

Comment: By the time the query result is returned, the information will be stale.

Answer (score 19):

568 according to this snippet I plugged into my browser's developer console when [sorted by users](https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users).

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mods-container>.mods-item').length
```

Thanks to [Mark's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334126/278148) for the tip to sort by users for better deduplication!

Comment: Thank you!  I knew there would be a simple geeky answer.

Answer (score 15):

If you switch the "group by" dropdown from "Sites" to "Users", it eliminates the duplicates.  Now all you have to do is count them; I get 553 (give or take [the current wave of resignations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/268944)).

Comment: I did not notice that feature, thanks.  Very helpful (and I appreciate someone else counting).

Comment: Why the discrepancy in totals? Are there that many cases of different display names?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, I probably mis-counted.

Comment: So only a handful of users are moderators in more that one site?

Comment: @Cyn, there are 71 commas on the page.  Subtract the three in the header, and you get at most 68 moderators who moderate more than one site.  More of my error-prone counting gives 51 multiple-site moderators.